# How to design a full screen application C#?

Tags: c#, .net, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to design a full screen application in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687693/whats-the-best-way-to-design-a-full-screen-application-in-c)

as you may know full screen forms do not fit on the IDE. So, I just wanted to know how I can position controls on that form.

Something like this:

```
 picturebox1.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 50(margin).
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your picture box in the right position relative to top and left border, then assure you have the

```
picturebox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

Comment: Hello, Steve. Thank you for your help but that code seems to do nothing with my pictureBox, this pictureBox is a close button so it needs to be on Top Right. Thank you.

Comment: OK then changed to the right. You put (in design mode) the picture box on your form in a position relative to the top/right border of your form (say pictureBox.Location(10,50)) and set the Anchor property. When you display your form to fullscreen, the picture box will move (has been anchored) with the top/right border of your form.

Comment: No, the `Anchor` property will not affect the size of your control  if you change font size or resolution provided you don't set the opposite values together (right/left or top/bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Anchor/Dock properties of yhour child controls, and in the designer, play with the size of the form using the mouse to stretch/shrink it - and make sure everything stays where you want it to!

Comment: Hello, Lohan. I'm scared it won't work on other resolutions, isn't there a better way to do it? I will not resize the form, I just want the controls to be in place without being affected by the user font size or resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying... the screen resolution+size will always affect the absolute position of the UI elements, unless you make a fixed-size container window.

Comment: Incidentally, you can just make the form bigger than the designer space and scroll the view around to see it.